# "Emulate" HTML5 audio buffer property in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, audio

Okay, so as part of the coursework I'm working on I've added some HTML5 `<audio>` tags. There is an element by the controls that is filled with `audio.buffered.end(0)/audio.duration*100+"%"` using the `onprogress` event.
However Firefox 3.6 (which is what the examinor will be using unless asked otherwise in the report) does not support the `onprogress` event or the `buffered` property. To fill in for this I've made the buffer indicator show `??%` instead, with a tooltip explaining that the buffer progress can't be read.

My question is this: **Is there some way of determining even an approximate value of the buffer progress? Is there a way of reading the number of bytes buffered and the total size of the audio file?**

It's not a huge deal if not, but if there is a way I would certainly love to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

It is possible to get the current network state via the networkState property.
However, this will only tell you whether buffering has finished, not the progress of that buffering.

Comment: Ah well. I'll just insert a reference to "Computer says no" in the tooltip, then. Thanks anyway :)